# K means implementation with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, k-means, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a k-means algorithm for a CNN that first of all calculate the centroids of the k-means.

I have a tensor of dims [80,1000] with the features of one layer of the CNN.
Then i randomly create a tensor of the same dims.

I calculate the euclidean dist. and take the minimum of this tensor. Then, i assign the new centroids corresponding to the index of the tensor with the features.

My problem is that i want to loop this until the centroids dont change their position but i am not very sure how i could achieve so and how to go updating the values received for the centroids.

the code is the following:

```
def k_means_torch(dictionary, model):
    centroids = torch.randn(len(dictionary), 1000).cuda()
    dist_centroids = torch.cdist(dictionary,centroids, p=2.0)
    (values, indices) = torch.min(dist_centroids, dim=1)
    centroids_new = dictionary[indices]
    x = False
    while (x != True) :
      print("Itera")
      dist_centroids_loop = torch.cdist(dictionary,centroids_new, p=2.0)
      (values_, indices_) = torch.min(dist_centroids_loop, dim=1)
      #idx = centroids_new == dictionary[indices_]
      #idx_ = idx.sum(1)
      if (torch.equal(centroids_new, dictionary[indices_])):
        print("yuhu se sale")
        x = True
      centroids_new = dictionary[indices_]
    return centroids_new
```

Any ideas are more than welcome